# Inequality in Coddington: Uniqueness of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Coddington's (and Levinson's) "Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations" and after proving existence of solutions for the initial value problem $f(t,y)=y'$, $y(\tau)=\xi$, he states and proves the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, is there any reason to take the interval (a,b) open? Doesn't the same proof work for a closed interval? Furthermore, if considering a closed interval [a,b], could $\tau = a$ or $\tau=b$?

I ask this because he always proves that solutions exist in closed intervals, and afterwards uses Theorem 2.1 as the cornerstone of the proof of uniqueness in closed intervals, in particular Theorem 2.3:

[image]

And theorem 2.1 in the book would only work for an open interval $(a,b)$, not for $[\tau-\alpha,\tau+\alpha]$. Or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: After looking at it some more, maybe one could prove that the solutions also coincide at the end points of the interval by passing to a limit, using the continuity of the solutions and $|.|$.
If $\phi,\psi$ are solutions with $\phi(\tau)=\psi(\tau)=\xi$ then:
$|\phi(\tau+\alpha)-\psi(\tau+\alpha)|=lim_{t->\tau+\alpha} |\phi(t)-\psi(t)|=0$, by theorem 2.1 
Does this work?